# From Code Snippit CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, forms

I need some help styling a form. I am using a platform called Growsurf and they provide the following code snippit:

```
<form action="https://growsurf.com/c/sfn4xx" method="POST" class="growsurf-button blue"> 
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (required)" required> 
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"> 
<input type="submit" value="Join Our Referral Program"> 
</form>
```

I need help updating the style but don't have a lot of coding experience. When the form deploys on my site some of the font is so tiny, you can barely read it. So, just need to know how to add style code to change the font.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: `.growsurf-button { /* your css */ }`

Answer (score 2):

So getting the class from your form for styling usese the `.` and then the class `growsurf-button` name in the style sheet.

it would look something like this for changing the font size, you can make it whatever though :)

```
.growsurf-button {
     font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will increase the font size for all inputs in the form:

```
.growsurf-font-lg input {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

And update the html to the following to make sure only forms with the growsurf-font-lg class have the font size increased:

```
<form action="https://growsurf.com/c/sfn4xx" method="POST" class="growsurf-button blue growsurf-font-lg"> 
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (required)" required> 
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Join Our Referral Program"> 
</form>
```

If you don't have a stylesheet to add to, you can always just use style tags like this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .growsurf-font-lg input {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
</style>

<form action="https://growsurf.com/c/sfn4xx" method="POST" class="growsurf-button blue growsurf-font-lg"> 
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (required)" required> 
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Join Our Referral Program"> 
</form>
```